# What can be done about the long URLs?

Tags: url

I'm used to using wikis with short, predictable URLs: host+page name.

Suddenly with SharePoint 2010 I'm confronted with long, apparently unpredictable paths to files.

I was triggered on this today when I wanted to email a colleague a link to a file on our company intranet in SharePoint. I *embedded the link in the text of the email* (using Outlook 2007) and tested it, only to find out that Outlook had not included the last few characters of the URL. I can insert the URL as *plain text*, of course, but that looks ugly.

Is there any generic way for SharePoint 2010 URLs to be shortened? Ideally I'm looking for a client side solution (equivalent to TinyURL) so that I don't have to go via IT. But if that's the only way, I'd still like to hear about it.

Comment: When you paste it in outlook, Can you try typing  < followed by your link followed by > ?

Comment: @Shoban - not sure what you mean - where does your text visible to the user go?

Comment: Sorry misunderstood your question! Thhought outlook is ignoring characters when you are pasting the link manually.

Comment: There is now a product called Short URL.  It seems enterprise grade, but it's *horribly* expensive...
https://www.shorturlapp.com/index.php 
I don't understand why Microsoft doesn't offer this out of the box.  For a while, I started using my own "file server" to get around some of this, but it's too much hassle.

Answer (score 4):

There is no OOB features for this in SharePoint, but it's quite easy to build. If you Bingle it you will find tons of samples; for instance: http://spurlshortener.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 4):

Joel Oleson [wrote about SharePoint URL Shorteners](http://www.collabshow.com/2011/05/03/url-shortener-these-sharepoint-urls-are-long/) some time ago.

One of his links point to [a product I worked on](http://www.muhimbi.com/Products/SharePoint-URL-Shortener/summary.aspx) so the usual disclaimers apply.

Comment: the Joel link is broken

Comment: Thanks, I have fixed it. Looks like the URL changed on that site.

Answer (score 2):

Wael Mohamed gives us [Create unique and shorten SharePoint URLs even the document moved using SharePoint Document ID](http://waelmohamed.wordpress.com/2013/06/10/create-unique-and-shorten-sharepoint-urls-even-the-document-moved-using-sharepoint-document-id/), without installing any 3rd part code or applications.

> ...Document ID introduce a unique URL based on unique ID for each
>   document “shorten link to the document”  even you move the document
>   itself from location to another or move the document library from site
>   to another.

basically the idea is to apply a custom DocumentID prefix, enabled under *Site Collection Administration*, and then use the ID when linking.

It's unclear to me whether the browser address bar url reflects the change or if using the doc-id in the url is something the author needs to do when sharing the link.